# Efficient way of getting SVD results from similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank, svd

Let's say we have a huge matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ where n is more than a million.

I would like to get a result of SVD as $U\Sigma V^{T} = A$.

Actually, the matrix $A$ is continuously changed slightly, for example, some of the rows are changed as follows
$A[i, :] \leftarrow a^{T}_{i}$.

Calculating the whole matrices for the updated $A$ takes a lot and I think it is inefficient. I would like to know if there is any way to reuse the past SVD results for the new SVD or so.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the notation $A[i, :] \leftarrow a^{T}_{i}$. Does $a_i^T$ bear any relation to $A$ before the reassignment of its $i$th row, or are you just using $a_i$ to denote the new value for the $i$th row?

Comment: The method [described outlined in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08369#) would allow you to (relatively) quickly update the SVD, one row at a time. Alternatively, you could look at your row changes collectively as a low-rank update/modification/perturbation and use some of the approaches from the references linked in the [second to last paragraph of this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179539/128205).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for sharing the links!